# firestore rules with custom functions error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a rule to allow certain functions in my firestore db (I worked with firebase since 3 months ago, I'm really new in this). The main idea is to find the _key of the user profile that I have stored in an user document. Then, search all the permissions allowed in the user-profiles document with the id that I found before. If I found the permission, I'd get access to the function

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function getPermisos(idPermiso){
    return get(/databases/{database}/documents/user-profiles/$(idPermiso)).data;
    }

    function getUserType(){
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.profile._key ;
    }


    match /proyectos/{document=**}{
    allow list,get: if getPermisos(getUserType()).acessList.proyectos==true;
    }


  }
}
```

Is this the right way to make it? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You don't query rules for accessibility. You can define a collection of `accessLevels` where each document represents your various access types such as "admins", "groupone", "grouptwo", etc. see [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

> #### Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules
>
> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user accounts. This
>   provides the ability to implement various access control strategies,
>   including role-based access control, in Firebase apps. These custom
>   attributes can give users different levels of access (roles), which
>   are enforced in an application's security rules.
>
> User roles can be defined for the following common cases:
>
> - Giving a user administrative privileges to access data and resources.
> - Defining different groups that a user belongs to.
> - Providing multi-level access:
> - Differentiating paid/unpaid subscribers.
> - Differentiating moderators from regular users.
> - Teacher/student application, etc.
> - Add an additional identifier on a user. For example, a Firebase user could map to a different UID in another system.

Comment: Yeah, this is something that I checked. And I realized that I can't use a function within another function. So I'm going to try it. Thanks